# Why are the unicode numbers not being selected in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, discord.js, emoji

I am creating a discord command to create a poll but for whatever reason, the emoji 1️⃣ wont pick up.

**MY CODE**

```
const EMOJIREGEX = /((?<!\\)<:[^:]+:(\d+)>)|\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic}/gmu;



  let element='1️⃣some text➡️'
        if (element.match(EMOJIREGEX)) {
          let emojis = element.match(EMOJIREGEX)
          console.log(emojis)
        
        } else {
        console.log('no emojis')
         
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[ '➡' ]
```

I've tried several other emojis and the 0-9 ones are the only ones that wont work (which is unfortunate because they're prolly the most important ones)

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but `if (element.match(EMOJIREGEX))` should be: `if (element.test(EMOJIREGEX))`

Comment: Is the idea to get the list of emojis present in the string?

Comment: @lucas_7_94 Yes well the first one anyway but i had it do all for an example, it collects it from a discord message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Emoji` instead of `Emoji_Presentation`

```js
const EMOJIREGEX = /((?<!\\)<:[^:]+:(\d+)>)|\p{Emoji}|\p{Extended_Pictographic}/gmu;

let element='1️⃣some text➡️'
let emojis = element.match(EMOJIREGEX);
if (emojis) {
  console.log(emojis)

} else {
console.log('no emojis')

}
```

List of aliases could be used:
https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropertyValueAliases.txt